# Multiple UI Frameworks detected - Intel XDK

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, intel, intel-xdk

I am using bootstrap framework for my mobile application in Intel XDK. However, i have included some JQuery UI feature like List View inside it. It is now giving me a sort of a warning that :

`Multiple ui frameworks detected in the document`

Is this something i should be worried about as of now the JQuery feature is working fine.

**UPDATE:** The jQuery listview does not appear in the Intel Emulator. But it appears in the Design view

Comment: It sounds like you're using App Designer to create your UI inside the XDK, is this correct? If so, I'll let the appropriate party know of this question.

Comment: yes I am using App designer

Comment: App Designer does some fancy stuff to disable a lot of the underlying JS code (for technical reasons I'm not qualified to fully explain), but that could explain why you see a difference in the App Designer preview compared to the emulator preview.

Comment: I've sent a message to the responsible engineer, he may be able to provide some more info on how to best proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQueryMobile?  (As opposed to jQuery UI, which is different).

When App Designer opens a document it tries to figure out which UI framework is being used so that it can display the right toolset to the user.  In your case it is discovering multiple UI frameworks. My guess is that it is seeing Bootstrap and jQueryMobile, and thus the warning.

jQueryMobile performs a *lot* of operations in the background and pretty much assumes it rules the roost once it is introduced into a project. It not only takes over a widgets DOM Node, it will take over the whole document.  JQM isn't elected lightly, you can't date her, you have to marry her.  I suspect this is why your listview isn't working in the Emulator - the normal JQM setup is absent.

One original goal for AppDesigner was to support multiple *simultaneous* frameworks, but that goal was quickly abandoned. Bootstrap and TopCoat aren't too bad, but most of the other frameworks are jealous ladies and they won't tolerate you flirting with components from other houses.

In summary, while I can guess as to what the underlying problem is, I don't have a simple solution.  You might try making a JQM project with App Designer and then manually insert some Bootstrap components into it.